# How can I mediate the JSON response of my API

Tags: wso2-api-manager, wso2-esb

Following one of the examples in the WSO2 documentation, I am invoking the Yahoo Weather API.  However, I would like to return a subset of the API's response values and rename some of them (e.g., return the only next day's High and Low and call them "NextDayHigh" and "NextDayLow".

Should I create a Script Mediator and manipulate the JSON that way?  How do I reference the individual fields from Yahoo's response and map them into a JSON response that I create?

Comment: you can select a subset using script mediator. https://docs.wso2.com/display/ESB481/Script+Mediator